# Speeding up "Mapcache_seed" with Mapserver

Tags: caching, gis, mapserver

I'm using `mapcache_seed` in the `mapcache` package to create a large image cache from calling my `mapserver` WMS, with vectors.

Currently, this is the command I'm using:

`sudo -u www-data mapcache_seed -c mapcache.xml -g WGS84 -n 8 -t Test -e\ [Foo,Bar,Baz,Fwee] -M 8,8 -z 12,13 --thread-delay 0 --rate-limit 10000`

Where `www-data` is my Nginx system-user, `mapcache.xml` is my config, `WGS84` is my SRS, `-n 8` is my logical thread count (on a i7-6700HQ at 3200 MHz), `-z 12,13` is one zoom level that needs to be seeded, thread-delay is off, and tile rate creation is set to 10000.

However, I only (max) get 50% total CPU utilization and most times only a single core goes above 50%. And an average of 500 tiles per second -- independent of how many threads or processes I specify. I've been trying to get all zoom-levels (4 to 27) seeded for the last couple of days, but I've only managed to get through 4-12, before being severely bottle-necked at a mere 3GB of a couple million tiles.

Memory utilization is at a stable 2.4% for 8GB PC4-2133 for mapcache_seed (0.5 for the WMS). Write speeds are at 100 MB/s, no-buffer write is also 100 MB/s, while buffered+cache is at 6.7-8.7 GB/s on a SATA III 1TB HDD. I have another SSD drive on my machine that gets 6 GB/s write and 8 GB/s read, but it's too small for storage and I'm afraid of drive failure from too many writes.

The cached tiles are around 4KB each and that means I get around 2MB worth of tiles every second. The majority of them aren't even tiles, but symlinks to a catch-all blank tile for empty tiles.

How would I go about speeding this process up? Messing with threads and limits, through `mapcache_seed`, does not make any discernible difference. This is also on a Debian Wheezy machine.

This is also being run through fast-cgi, using 256x256 px images, and disk cache with a restricted extent to a single country (otherwise mapcache starts generating nothing but symlinks to blank tiles, because more than 90% of the world is blank!)

Mapserver mapfile (redacted):

```
MAP
   NAME         "MAP"
   SIZE         1200 800
   EXTENT       Foo Bar Baz Fwee
   UNITS        DD
   SHAPEPATH        "."
   IMAGECOLOR   255 255 255
   IMAGETYPE        PNG
   WEB
     IMAGEPATH  "/path/to/image"
     IMAGEURL   "/path/to/imageurl"
     METADATA
        "wms_title"                     "MAP"
        "wms_onlineresource"            "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?MAP=/path/to/map.map"
        "wms_srs"                       "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_feature_info_mime_type"    "text/plain"
        "wms_abstract"                  "Lorem ipsum"
        "ows_enable_request"            "*"
        "wms_enable_request"            "*"
     END
   END

PROJECTION
  "init=epsg:4326"
END

   LAYER
     NAME       base
     TYPE       POLYGON
     STATUS     OFF
     DATA       polygon.shp
     CLASS
        NAME        "Polygon"
        STYLE
          COLOR     0 0 0
          OUTLINECOLOR  255 255 255
        END
     END
   END

   LAYER
     NAME       outline
     TYPE       LINE
     STATUS     OFF
     DATA       line.shp
     CLASS
       NAME     "Line"
       STYLE
         OUTLINECOLOR   255 255 255
       END
     END
   END  
END
```

mapcache.xml (redacted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mapcache>
<source name="ms4wserver" type="wms">
<getmap>
  <params>
    <LAYERS>base</LAYERS>
        <MAP>/path/to/map.map</MAP>
  </params>
</getmap>
<http>
  <url>http://localhost/wms/</url>
</http>
  </source>

<cache name="disk" type="disk">
<base>/path/to/cache/</base>
<symlink_blank/>
  </cache>

  <tileset name="test">
<source>ms4wserver</source>
<cache>disk</cache>
<format>PNG</format>
<grid>WGS84</grid>
<metatile>5 5</metatile>
<metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
<expires>3600</expires>
  </tileset>

   <default_format>JPEG</default_format>

   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
 <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
  <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
  <format>JPEG</format>
  <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
   </service>
   <service type="wmts" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="tms" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="kml" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="gmaps" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="ve" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="mapguide" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="demo" enabled="false"/>

   <errors>report</errors>
   <locker type="disk">
 <directory>/path/</directory>
 <timeout>300</timeout>
</locker>

</mapcache>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone coming across this ten years later, when what's left of the little documentation for these tools has rotted away, I messed with my mapcache and mapfile settings to get something better. It wasn't that my generation was too slow, it was that I was generating TOO MANY GODDAMN SYMLINKS to blank files. First, the mapfile extent was incorrect. Second, I was using the "WGS84" grid, which by default seeds ALL extents. That means 90% of all my tiles were just symlinks to a blank.png, and it ate up ALL of my inodes. I recommend using `mkdir blank; rsync -a --delete blank/ /path/to/cache` for a quick clearing of all that mess.

I fixed the above by taking the WGS84 specifications and changing the extent to the one I specified in my mapfile. Now, only my mapfile gets seeded. Lastly, I appended the grid XML element like so:

```
<grid restricted_extent="MAP FILE EXTENT HERE">GRIDNAME</grid>
```

With `restricted_extent` now it's certain that only my map gets seeded. I had over 100 million tiles, but they were all goddamn symlinks! Otherwise, I got a "Ran out of space" or something of some such. Even if `df` shows that the partition isn't full, it's misleading. Symlinks take up inode space, not logical space! To see inode space, run `df -hi`. I was at 100% inode space, but only 1% logical space on a 1TB drive -- filled with goddamn symlinks!